# Indentation of the second line in a very lone sentence after \textbullet WITHOUT itemize environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, itemize

I have a very long sentence after a `\textbullet`. Because it is very lone, it goes to the second line. But there is no indentation in the second line. How could I add indentation and align the second line of this sentence to its first line after the `\textbullet`?

I know this can be easily done with the itemize environment. But there are some reasons that I **cannot** use the itemize environment or any other list or table structures (**Enumerate**, **Description**, **tabular**, or **tabularx**). I have to use `\textbullet` in the plain text.

Here is what I got with `\textbullet`:
[image: Here is what I got with \textbullet:]

Here is what I expected to have:
[image: Here is what I expected to have:]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\textbullet\ Long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{itemize}\item <long sentence>\end{itemize}`

Comment: What's the problem with `itemize`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the hanging indent:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newlength\boxwid
\settowidth{\boxwid}{\indent\textbullet\ }
\hangindent=\boxwid
\textbullet\ Long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As per the request below, you can redefine `\textbullet` to include this in each call. I should add that this is **not** advisable in general, as `\textbullet` may be used elsewhere. A better approach would be to wrap this in an environment (e.g., `itemize`, @egreg's suggestion in the comments) or a command (similar to @Bernard's answer). Regardless, you asked, so here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\boxwid%  
\let\oldtextbullet=\textbullet
\def\textbullet{%
    \settowidth{\boxwid}{\indent\oldtextbullet\ }%
    \hangindent=\boxwid%
    \oldtextbullet}
\begin{document}

\textbullet\ Long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much. But is there any way to summarize the code `\newlength\boxwid
\settowidth{\boxwid}{\indent\textbullet\ }
\hangindent=\boxwid` into a new command in preamble and use that to replace `\textbullet`? I have tried it in preamble, but it failed to compile.

Comment: @englealuze: Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution modifying `leftskip` within a command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\hangbullet[1]{\leftskip1.5\parindent
\hspace*{-\parindent}\leavevmode\llap{{\textbullet\enspace}}#1\par\leftskip0pt}

\begin{document}

\hangbullet{Long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text, long text.}

\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm 7 years late to the party, but this 2022 version is bit easier to consume. Use the package [`hang`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hang?lang=en) to achieve this, and set the hang length to any units LaTeX understands using `\setlength{\hangingindent}{⟨length⟩}` in the hang environment.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hang}

\begin{document}
    \textbullet{ }\lipsum[1]
    
    \setlength{\hangingindent}{5mm}
    \begin{hangingpar}
        \textbullet{ }\lipsum[1]
    \end{hangingpar}
    
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Nice. Can you please adapt your solution to \textbullet ?

Comment: @MS-SPO I guess adding \textbullet just before lipsum[1] on the third-last-line should do the trick. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Please check AND modify your answer accordingly, so everything is in one place only.

Comment: @MS-SPO. Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited the answer accordingly.