# What is the default size of my list indentation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, indentation

### Question

I want to put a non-float tabular environment inside of a `description` list after a line break.  I want said table to left align with the labels.  What value does the `description` environment use for an indent?

### MWE (default behavior)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{description}
    \item [$\vert$ line me up]
    ~\\
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      $\vert$ here & more text \\
      $\vert$ and here & even more text 
    \end{tabular}
    \item [$\vert$ some other item]
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

### MWE (closer to what I want)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{description}
    \item [$\vert$ line me up]
    ~\\
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\hspace{-1.1cm}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      $\vert$ here & more text \\
      $\vert$ and here & even more text 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \item [$\vert$ some other item]
  \end{description}
  
\end{document}
```

[image: An example of the second MWE shows that the vertical lines are not aligned.]

### The question restated

In the second example, I would like to replace `1.1cm` with whatever internal spacing value my document class uses to indent following a list item.  I imagine it would be something like `\listindent`.

- Does this variable/constant exist?
- If not, how can I find the spacing my document class is using?
- Is there a better or more elegant way to align these things?

### What this question is not.

- I do not want to align the description text only like in [How to control enumitem's description list via leftmargin and labelwidth keys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23559/how-to-control-enumitems-description-list-via-leftmargin-and-labelwidth-keys)
- I would like to avoid redefining the `description` environment a la: [Indentation of the second line in a very lone sentence after \textbullet WITHOUT itemize environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274091/indentation-of-the-second-line-in-a-very-lone-sentence-after-textbullet-without) .  Surely a value already exists inside the system to accomplish this.
- I think this is a novel question based on my search.  Please point me in the right direction if this is a duplicate.

Comment: not totally related but `~\\ ` is rather weird input and probably not what is intended.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Good catch, but it is intentional for the hacky MWE.  The ``$\vert$ line me up`` should be in brackets for the ``description`` format.  To force a line break after that requires character, hence the forced space.

Comment: No `~\\ ` is just always wrong, even in a MWE. Just leave a blank line. `line me up ~\\ ` happens to work here but forces _two_ spaces before the line break so if  `line me up` happened to be longer (within two spaces of the right margin)  `~\\ ` would force two line breaks, with one extra line just carring the space tokens.

Comment: I edited the MWE to show you what I mean.  The description item text not in the label is placed immediately following the label, regardless of the natural carriage return line breaks.  I need to somehow force a linebreak with ``\\``.  Without the ``~`` the compiler complains that there is no line there to end.

Comment: changing `\item xxx` to `\item[xxx]` changes the question rather a lot:-) Never use `~\\ ` you could use `\mbox{}\\ `

Answer (score 1):

Several changes are required.  Use the `enumitem` package.  Specify `\leftmargin` for the indent of the environment, specify `itemindent=0pt` to left align the table to the left margin, and specify your tabular specification with a leading `@{}`, so that no `tabular` margin is applied to the first column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,enumitem}

\begin{document}
\noindent Left margin
  \begin{description}[leftmargin=3pt, itemindent=0in]
    \item $\vert$ line me up
    ~\\
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
      $\vert$ here & more text \\
      $\vert$ and here & even more text 
    \end{tabular}
    \item $\vert$ some other item
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A specification of `[leftmargin=5pt]` seems to adjust the line inputs without adjusting the default `description` indent.

Comment: From what I read, using the ``@{}`` ``tabular`` option seems more canonical.  However, it seems like an extra step compared to @Bernard's answer.  Why would I want to take the extra step to use ``@{}`` AND increase the ``pagemargin`` by 4pt?

Comment: @WesH The tabular margin can be locally changed either by the user or the document class, and is set by the length `\tabcolsep`.  Its default value in the `article` class is 6pt, which you can determine via `\the\tabcolsep`.  You need to understand that increasing a pagemargin by a physical value (e.g., +4pt) will likely work only for the particulars of a given document class, or even of a particular user's preference.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \begin{document}

      \begin{description}[leftmargin=-1pt, labelindent=0pt]
        \item $\vert$ line me up
        ~\\
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
          $\vert$ here & more text \\
          $\vert$ and here & even more text
        \end{tabular}
        \item $\vert$ some other item
      \end{description}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is functional.  But what was the original ``labelindent`` and ``leftmargin``?

Comment: Normally, in a description environment,  labelindentis 0pt. I don't lnpw the exact value of leftmargin (probably a fraction of labelwidth) and the value I used was found by trial & error.